Using the symmetry of the normal to find $E(Z|Y)$ given $Z\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y=Z^2$
I know that this question has been answered before; namely here.
I'm really struggling to understand the formulation of how this answer was reached. Specifically, as someone pointed out in the comments, "how does one get $p(\sqrt{y})+p(-\sqrt{y})=0$ from the expectation?". I understand the intuition - that by the symmetry of the normal, $\sqrt{y}$ and $-\sqrt{y}$ have equal probabilities, but what property of expectation allows for this kind of calculation? Since $Z$ is a continuous RV, wouldn't $p(\pm\sqrt{y})$ be zero regardless?

If you would read and understand the answer to the question you cite, the explanation is right there. $Z$ is unconditionally a standard normal random variable, but conditioned  on the value of $Y = Z^2$ being, say, $\alpha \geq 0$, the conditional distribution of $Z$ is that of a discrete random variable taking on values $\pm \sqrt\alpha$ with equal probability $\frac 12$. As a special case, if $\alpha = 0$, $Z = 0$ with probability $1$. Cross your eyes and dot your teas to write the conditional expected value of $Z$ given that $Y = \alpha$ as
$$E[Z\mid Y = \alpha] = \begin{cases}(\sqrt\alpha)\cdot \frac 12 + (-\sqrt\alpha)\cdot \frac 12 = 0, & \alpha > 0,\\
0\cdot 1 = 0, & \alpha = 0, \end{cases} \tag{1}$$
and so $E[Z\mid Y = \alpha] = 0$ regardless of the value of $\alpha$.
Consequently, $$E[Z \mid Y] = E[Z \mid Z^2] = 0.$$
